# Movements don't work the way it should

Tags: unity, c#, movement

I'm trying to make some basic animation, but I ran into this problem. Whenever I move with WASD, it teleports instead of doing the walking animation. Also the idle plays only one time, then it stops:
https://i.imgur.com/zZY6w7J.gifv

My animator setup and the console: [image]

The code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AppleInput : MonoBehaviour
{
private Animator animator;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    animator.SetFloat("Vertical", Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
}
}
```

Update:
[image]

**Forgot to mention, that my character can't move further away, when I release the W key for forward, it comes back to its original place just like in gif.**

Comment: You'll want to show us how you configured each of those animations.

Comment: @DMGregory Is there a way to just share my project file? I feel like I could waste everyone's time because I usually give incorrect answers and then people have to explain a lot more. Anyways, I updated the post, but I'm not sure if it's what you wanted. Like I said, I'm pretty new here and tried searching up on Google for this, but all I got was how to make teleportations, or I just don't know how to look for this up.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to take more time working your way through beginner tutorials then, as they'll explain it step-by-step from first principles.

Comment: I was following tutorials and had watched a beginner's course, but I guess I can't remember a lot of theory.